# C++ - building libraries

Tags: c++, visual-studio, build, libraries

I'm building static libraries (right now `libpng`) in Microsoft Visual Studio 2008 SP1.

Do I have any possibility to build *single* library (one file) for both `Debug` and `Release` modes assuming that my library has only C code in it?

As far as I remember, `gtkmm`, for instance, has it's pre-built package, where C++ based libraries are shipped in both `Debug` and `Release` versions, but other - as a single file only.

E.g. they have `gtkmm-vc90-d-2_4.lib` and `gtkmm-vc90-2_4.lib` files for C++ based libraries and they have single libraries such as `gtk-win32-2.0.lib` for both `Debug` and `Release` configurations.

***How can I achieve the same effect? What should I do to make the built library (pure C) configuration-independent?***

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In theory you could build just one library **if** all the external headers for the library (ie the ones pulled in by the client) don't use #ifdef _DEBUG (or any other macro that may be defined in a debug build but not a release build.

Consider a case like this:

```
// file: mylib.h
struct A {
   int member1;
   int member2;
   #ifdef _DEBUG
     int extraDebugOption;
   #endif
};
```

In this case, if you were to link the library into a debug build of your own product then A will have a different size to the release build, which means you're going to have some pretty horrendous memory corruption bugs to track down (been there...).

EDIT: 
Forgot to mention, you should make your one configuration a Release configuration so that you don't end up with any references to the debug CRT, and also so the library is optimised.  As lsalamon points out, creating a pdb file and saving this along with your .lib file will be useful in the future for debugging.

Comment: And how should I deal with `/NODEFAULTLIB` warnings when using library  build as `Debug` in my `Release` app?

Comment: Probably the safest way would be to statically link against the release runtime.

Answer (score 1):

To include debug info at release version use this configuration :
C/C++->General->Debug Information Format: Program Database (/Zi)
and 
Linker->Debugging->Generate Debug Info : Yes (/DEBUG)

Comment: These settings are default for `vc90`, as far as I remember.

Comment: For the release configuration too? (since the OP should probably be building effectively a release configuration of this library)